# Streaming mp3 with RTP using gstreamer in Windows

Tags: window, mp3, rtp, gstreamer

I used the following pipelines in Ubuntu to stream mp3 and it worked fine.

Sender:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=/home/file.mp3 ! mad ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1,depth=16,width=16, rate=44100 ! rtpL16pay  ! udpsink host=192.168.1.103 port=5000
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, width=(int)16, height=(int)16, encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, channel-position=(int)1, payload=(int)96" ! gstrtpjitterbuffer do-lost=true ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! alsasink sync=false
```

But when I used the same in Windows it is not working. I can hear it is playing only at the very beginning but for only small time. Destination receives the media, but I cannot hear the sound. Here are the pipelines used,

Sender:

```
gst-launch -v filesrc location=C:/file.mp3 ! mad ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1,depth=16,width=16, rate=44100 ! rtpL16pay  ! udpsink host=192.168.1.105 port=5000
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, payload=(int)96" ! gstrtpjitterbuffer do-lost=true ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink sync=false
```

*Gstreamer OSSBUILD* is used in Windows. Please kindly help me to solve the issue.

If required, following are the outputs on the terminal,

Sender:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMad:mad0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endiannes
s=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)32, depth=(int)32, rate=(int)44100
, channels=(int)2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-
raw-int, endianness=(int)4321, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)1
6, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x
-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)32, depth=(int)
32, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw-
int, endianness=(int)4321, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, r
ate=(int)44100, channels=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw
-int, endianness=(int)4321, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16,
rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-
rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(string)L16, enco
ding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1331970475,
clock-base=(uint)3177922110, seqnum-base=(uint)10029
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-i
nt, endianness=(int)4321, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, ra
te=(int)44100, channels=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0: timestamp = 3177922110
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0: seqnum = 10029
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp
, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(string)L16, encodin
g-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1331970475, clo
ck-base=(uint)3177922110, seqnum-base=(uint)10029
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 40987345000 ns.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0.GstPad:sink: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0.GstPad:src: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMad:mad0.GstPad:src: caps = NULL
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Receiver:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0.GstPad:src: caps = ap
plication/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(stri
ng)L16, encoding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, payload=(int)96
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0.GstPad:sink: caps = a
pplication/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(str
ing)L16, encoding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, payload=(int)96
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Depay:rtpl16depay0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-ra
w-int, endianness=(int)4321, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16,
rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)1, channel-positions=(GstAudioChannelPosition)<
GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_FRONT_MONO >
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Depay:rtpl16depay0.GstPad:sink: caps = applicati
on/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, encoding-name=(string)L16,
encoding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, payload=(int)96
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-
raw-int, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)tru
e, channels=(int)1, rate=(int)44100, channel-positions=(GstAudioChannelPosition)
< GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_FRONT_MONO >
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x
-raw-int, endianness=(int)4321, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)
16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)1, channel-positions=(GstAudioChannelPosition
)< GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_FRONT_MONO >
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoAudioSink:autoaudiosink0/GstWaveFormSink:autoaudio
sink0-actual-sink-waveform.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, width=(int)16, d
epth=(int)16, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, channels=(int)1, rate=
(int)44100, channel-positions=(GstAudioChannelPosition)< GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSIT
ION_FRONT_MONO >
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoAudioSink:autoaudiosink0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps =
audio/x-raw-int, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boo
lean)true, channels=(int)1, rate=(int)44100, channel-positions=(GstAudioChannelP
osition)< GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_FRONT_MONO >
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoAudioSink:autoaudiosink0.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxy
Pad:proxypad0: caps = audio/x-raw-int, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, endianness=
(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, channels=(int)1, rate=(int)44100, channel-posit
ions=(GstAudioChannelPosition)< GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_FRONT_MONO >
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you dump to a file instead of auto audio sync and check. That will tell you if the rest of the pipeline is ok.  I would keep removing one element at a time from the end of the reciever pipeline and append the file sink instead to find out which element is the culprit. Instead of auto audio sink why not use a specific audio sink. That could also be the problem.

You have a simple pipeline: Do that following through elimination

1. Ensure the input is indeed coming continously

src -> filesink

src -> depay -> filesink

Go this way till you find the wrong element.

your file size should keep growing. Which ever element causes it not to work anymore is the culprit. If it is the audiosink then use one explicit one instead of autoaudiosink.

You could introduce a queue and check. 
Run with GST_DEBUG=3 or 4 or 5 with increasing debug information to check the culprit.Lot of debugging options left.